# Docker for Mac VM IP

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I just migrated to using Docker for Mac, from previously using Docker Toolbox with virtualbox for OSX.

I used to get the machine IP address with `$(docker-machine ip default)`.

Is there a reliable way to get the Hyperkit IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need for working with the xhyve VM's IP address directly like you would with `docker-machine`. All port mappings are directly mapped to `localhost`.

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx:latest
$ curl localhost:8080
```

Also see the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/):

> When you run a container with the `-p` argument, for example: `$ docker run -p 80:80 -d nginx` Docker for Mac will make the container port available at `localhost`.

Comment: ok thanks! this is helpful.  There are cases for me where the actual VM IP would still be useful - but this is great for now.

Comment: I downvote because it doesnt answer the question. I want to know how to get the ip. I know how to map ports.

Answer (score 33):

In opposition to **Docker toolbox**, **Docker for Windows** and **Docker for Mac** are designed to give you the feeling that **Docker** is running directly on your OS, so they use lightweight virtual machines running under lightweight hypervisors (instead of **VirtualBox**) handled directly by the **docker** executable.
Hence you won't see them with **docker-machine** and you won't see another IP address than **localhost**.

**Docker for Windows** relies on the **HyperV** hypervisor which allows a network connection to `tcp://localhost:2375`.

**Docker for Mac** relies on the **xhyve** hypervisor, the way it's implemented only provides a connection through the socket `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

### Workaround

To provide a TCP connection for **Docker for Mac**:

1. Install **socat**. With **brew**:

   `brew install socat`
2. Run this **socat** command to forward TCP requests to the socket

   `socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,reuseaddr,fork,bind=localhost UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock`
3. Map what you want on `tcp://localhost:2375`

Up to you to run the **socat** command on startup, if necessary.

This was for instance useful to me to associate the *Webstorm nodeJS debugger* to a *nodeJS* container (since at the time of writing, *docker debugging* is supported by *Webstorm docker integration plugin*, but not through unix sockets).

### Documentation on Docker for Mac limitations

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#/known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds

> **There is no docker0 bridge on macOS**
>
> Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker for Mac, you cannot see a docker0 interface in macOS. This interface is actually within HyperKit.

Answer (score 11):

You could use docker image for socat which starts every time you start 'docker for mac'

> docker run -d --restart=always -p 2376:2375 -v
>   /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock bobrik/socat
>   TCP4-LISTEN:2375,fork,reuseaddr UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock

Find your docker API ip address:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet 192'| awk '{ print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

My current solution is to create the containers using Docker Machine (A linux VM which is available under another IP address) and route all the traffic of the containers to the docker machine VM.

```
sudo route -n add -net 172.18.0.0/16 192.168.99.100
```

You can get the network range of your docker containers using `docker inspect` and the IP address of your docker machine VM using `docker-machine ip`

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.17.0.1` so you can still use the same static IP address (if your Linux-based colleagues or bash scripts insist on using that).